# JSP look through the object list

Tags: java, spring, jsp, model-view-controller

So, i have a custom object or a list of object (Custom, by custom i mean it contains an int, a date, a string and a Double value). I have it saved in the list in the controller.
Everything is working so far, but when i go to the JSP view and i want to show these details, I dont know how to do that.

Code is here ...
Controller:

```
List<Object> orders = new ArrayList<Object>();
orders.add(order.getId());
orders.add(order.getDate());
orders.add(prdtDiscript);
orders.add(cost);

model.addAttribute("orderList", orders);
```

View:

```
<table class="TFtable">

    <c:forEach begin="0" end="${orderList}" varStatus="orders">
    <tr>
        <td><h3>Id</h3></td>
        <td><c:out value="${orders}"></c:out></td>

        <td><h3>Date</h3></td>
        <td><c:out value="${orders.getDate()}"></c:out></td>    

        <td><a href="/order/orderDetail?orderId=${ordera.getId()}">Edit</a></td>
        <td><a href="/order/delete?orderId=${orders.getId()}">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>   
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

the first line in the view i got from some internet example, but i  could not get from here to the next step, most of time we have an object where we can do some .get() operations, to get the values. But as i said it is a custom object and I dont have access to any sort of methods and the values are just there. just dont know how to get them.
Let say that the first 4 line of the list would look like some what this:

```
0: 1 
1: 03/11/2016
2: some string 
3: 34
```

now the rest of the list follows the same pattern ...

Sorry I should have put the calculation part as well, just in case it helps other to understand what i mean:

```
List<Object> orders = new ArrayList<Object>();
String prdtDiscript = "";
Double cost = 0.0;

for (Order order: EMarketApp.getStore().getOrderList()){
    int i = 0;

    if (!order.getProducts().isEmpty())             
        for (Product product: order.getProducts()){             
            if (i== 0)
                prdtDiscript = prdtDiscript +  product.getName();
            else if (i > 0 )
                prdtDiscript = prdtDiscript + ", " + product.getName();
            i++;
            Double price =product.getPrice();
            int amount =  order.getSinglePrdtAmount(product.getId());
            cost += price * amount;
        }
    orders.add(order.getId());
    orders.add(order.getDate());
    orders.add(prdtDiscript);
    orders.add(cost);

}
```

any help is appreciated ...

Comment: What on earth are you doing. Why not just pass a list of orders?

Comment: Yeah, that is a possibility, I did not do that because I dont have the description which is the name of all the products, and the cost which is the total price calculated based on product price * product quantity. so i have to calculate it before i send it to jsp. I dont know how to do in JSP.

Comment: i put there the calculation code if you can tell how would i do that in jsp